# implementing scanner using phonegap

Tags: android, cordova

I was using Android SDK for my application development. Now I am in a situation to move on cross platform development so, I started learning Phonegap as it is well suitable for cross platform.

I want to use external scanner device and card swipper with android device. I googled it but i didnt find any useful ideas.

I explored phonegap.com/ but it explains only about using device sensors,contacts and media information..etc. But It didnt say about implementing external hardware devices.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a barcode scanner, you probably want to get a bluetooth capable device, as USB devices can be problematic to connect to different devices. Start by using it in HID mode, which emulates a keyboard (nb, doesnt play nice on iPad and other apple devices, popup keyboard disappears, but android ok). Later you can try using SPP mode. When using HID mode with phonegap, you dont need to do anything special, just read as keystrokes in html pages.

There is also a phonegap plugin for zxing to use the camera, but you asked about external physical scanners, which are faster for bulk scanning.

Haven't tried connecting card swipe readers to android yet